# Orthogonal functions and linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, special-functions, hilbert-spaces, legendre-polynomials

Consider the following function $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, expanded in terms of Legendre functions,
$$
f(y;\boldsymbol{\beta}) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \beta_i P_i(y)
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ are the expansion coefficients.

**Question:**
Does there exist another set of expansion coefficients $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$ such that
$$
\left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\beta}) \right| = \left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\gamma}) \right|
$$
for all $y \in [-1,1]$? My approach so far is to treat $\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\gamma}$ as vectors in some infinite dimensional vector space $V$, and assume there exists an invertible linear operator $X: V \rightarrow V$ so that
$$
\boldsymbol{\gamma} = X \boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
Then the function $f(y;\boldsymbol{\beta})$ can be written as
$$
f(y; \boldsymbol{\beta}) = A(y) \boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
where $A(y): V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear operator. I would like to define "rows" of this operator as being specific to some $y \in [-1,1]$, in other words,
$$
A(y) = \pmatrix{a_{y_1}^T \\ a_{y_2}^T \\ \vdots \\ a_{y_{\infty}^T}}
$$
where the vector $a_y \in V$ is
$$
(a_y)_j = P_j(y)
$$
Now I have written the rows of $A$ with a discrete index $1,2,\dots,\infty$, but of course $y \in [-1,1]$ is a continuous variable, so in fact $A$ would have uncountably infinitely many rows, one for each $y \in [-1,1]$ but it would have countably infinitely many columns, one for each $P_j(x)$, $j=0,\dots,\infty$.

**Progress so far**

**Observation 1:**
The condition $\left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\beta}) \right| = \left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\gamma}) \right|$ leads to
$$
\boldsymbol{\beta}^T A^T(y) A(y) \boldsymbol{\beta} = \boldsymbol{\beta}^T X^T A^T(y) A(y) X \boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
Since this is true for all $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in V$, the equation $X$ must satisfy is
$$
X^T A^T(y) A(y) X = A^T(y) A(y)
$$
for all $y \in [-1,1]$.

**Observation 2:** There are two trivial solutions to the above equation, namely
$$
X = \pm I
$$
where $I$ is the identity operator on my vector space $V$.

**Observation 3:** The set of all solutions $X$ which satisfy the above equation forms a group. Above I assumed that $X$ is invertible, and the identity element is part of the set of solutions from Observation 2. Group closure can be readily verified also.

**Observation 4:** if $X$ is a solution to the problem, then $X + K^T$ is also a solution, where $K$ is defined as any linear operator such that $a_y \in Ker(K)$ for all $y \in [-1,1]$.

This is true because we can write $A^T(y) A(y)$ as
$$
A^T(y) A(y) = \sum_{y \in [-1,1]} a_y a_y^T
$$
so when $K$ acts on this sum from the left (or $K^T$ from the right), it will annihilate the vectors $a_y$. **Unfortunately, I don't know if there exist any such $K$ operators!**

**SUB-QUESTIONS**

**Sub-question 1:** Can anyone suggest a way to approach the problem of finding all possible $X$ operators satisfying the above equation?

**Sub-question 2:** So far I have been looking at the infinite dimensional vector space $V$, but I would also be quite interested in any solutions to the finite-dimensional problem of truncating the series for $f$ at some value $N$, and considering a finite set of points $y_i, i=1,\dots,M$ with $M>N$. Here $f$ would be defined as
$$
f(y;\boldsymbol{\beta}) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} \beta_i P_i(y)
$$
and I would seek solutions to
$$
\left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\beta}) \right| = \left| f(y; \boldsymbol{\gamma}) \right|
$$
only on the finite set of points $y \in \{y_1,\dots,y_M\}$. Here, $A$ would become a $M \times N$ matrix, $X$ would be $N \times N$, and the dimension of $V$ is $N$.

In this finite dimensional case, because $M > N$, the vectors $a_{y_i}$, $i=1,\dots,M$ won't be linearly independent, and so I don't think there will exist any $K$ matrices whose kernel contain the $a_{y_i}$. Perhaps if we chose $N > M$ we could find $K$ matrices in that case...

**Disclaimer**

It is possible, and even likely, that I have been sloppy with my assumptions and notation about infinite dimensional linear operators. For example I don't know if it makes sense to talk about the transpose of an infinite dimensional linear operator, though from what I defined above it makes sense to me. I apologize if I have used incorrect notation (I have a physics background).

Comment: I'm a bit confused - doesn't your Observation 2 answer your original question? Are you excluding the answer $X=-I$ as being too trivial? One can of course generalize this, e.g., to $g(y)=sign(y)f(y)$ (or other arbitrary choices of intervals in $y$ where the $f$, $g$ differ by a sign), and then $f$ and $g$ will have different expansion coefficients, yet their absolute values will agree for all $y$. If you're really picky, you could insist on sign changes happening only at zeroes of $f$, $g$ ...

Comment: Well, I am looking for all possible solutions $X$. So far I found two solutions $\pm I$ but there may be more out there. Essentially I want to find the full group of elements $X$ which satisfy this.

Comment: Well, as I note, you can put arbitrary sign changes anywhere on the interval, so those are quite a lot of additional solutions ... and I suspect that's it, because what other functions would agree in absolute value ...

Comment: Yes that is something I hadn't considered, thank you! However, consider the finite-dimensional case where $N > M$. In this case, $A^T A = \sum_{i=1}^M a_i a_i^T$, and we could find some $N \times N$ matrix $K$ such that $a_i \in Ker(K)$ for all $i=1,\dots,M$ because the $a_i$ would span only a lower dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$. So by Observation 4 there will exist more solutions of the form $\pm I + K^T$. So I think there might be a richer set of solutions than simple sign changes...

Comment: But do such additional solutions really give you additional pairs $\beta $, $\gamma $? In the space of functions $f$, which seems to me to be much more straightforward to think in, it's hard to see what else you could do besides sign change if you want to keep absolute values equal.

Comment: So in the space of functions $f$, your group action would be multiplication by arbitrary functions $p$ that satisfy $p=\pm 1$ for all $y$.

Comment: Hmm I am beginning to agree that for the continuous case sign changes might be the only solution. But I think for the finite-dimensional case, where we only demand $|f(y)| = |g(y)|$ at $M$ discrete points there might be more interesting solutions.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, in terms of the functions $f$, it remains true that all you can do is sign changes at any of the $M$ discrete points. However, if $M>N$, then in general the $\beta_{i} $ won't even exist, since you're not using a complete basis, no?

Comment: Ah - you also mention $N>M$. Then, the $P_i (y)$ aren't linearly independent on the set of $M$ points, so of course then you can trade coefficients off against one another. That's indeed an additional freedom, but not one that usually would be considered very meaningful. It's not a freedom connected to your particular question $|f|=|g|$, but a freedom you would have anywhere in linear algebra if you used more than  a minimal set of basis vectors to span your space.